# UISearchBar scope bar invisible in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar

With the following code the scope bar is invisible (buttons work but are not visible - just black space)

```
UISearchBar* searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 44 + (_showScope?40:0));];
searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"string1", @"string2", nil];
searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
searchBar.delegate = self;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

works fine in iOS6.  Any ideas?

Comment: Add NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.tableView.frame)); I think you'll find some interesting things (due to iOS7). (I would assume self.tableView.frame.size.width is 0).

Comment: thanks, but nope not it - {{0, 0}, {320, 548}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems to be a workaround:

```
UISearchBar* searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"string1", @"string2", nil];
searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
searchBar.delegate = self;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 44 + (_showScope?40:0));
```

nice!

Comment: have you tried to set background image of search bar? Based on your code, I add [searchBar setBackgroundImage......]. But not working, I use UISearchDisplayController to add search bar, and set the search bar background, the background shows, but the scope bar always shows as a black bar. Please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226503/ios-7-scope-bar-becomes-black-in-search-mode

Comment: This worked well for me.  Thank you.  I wonder if setting the bar style is necessary though.  I removed that bit and still managed to overcome this issue.

Comment: depends wether you want the bar black or not, but no its not part of the solution...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Nick H247 for getting me on the right track.  However, his workaround produced another issue for me where the search result list was being displayed behind the search bar, making it so I was unable to select search results from the beginning of the list. I fixed this by setting the frame *before* assigning the UISearchBar to the tableHeaderView.

```
UISearchBar* searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"string1", @"string2", nil];
searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
searchBar.delegate = self;

searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 44 + (_showScope?40:0));

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, calls searchBar.sizeToFit;